# InDesign - Hide things outside the artboard (no preview mode)

Tags: adobe-indesign

How do I hide all things which are going out of my inDesign pages while still maintaining grids etc (no preview mode)?
I know, I can adjust the bounding boxes, but that takes more time

Comment: By "things which are going out of my InDesign pages", do you mean page items that are partly on your page and partly off your page? Because that would be a totally different question from the one you asked initially …

Answer (score 4):

Just tap the `W` key. It will hide everything off the pages and the guides.

...or `View > Screen Mode > Preview` from the menu. Same thing, but the `W` is just easier.

---

Just semantics. Indesign doesn't have "artboards". They are pages in InDesign, unless they have drastically altered things in CC2020.

Comment: That is more of a workaround.

Comment: @Woww In what way is it a "workaround"??? The preview is a feature of InDesign and is specifically there to do what you asked -- Hide things outside the pages. Do you mean you want to cut or clip things outside pages?

Comment: Or.. since you are using terms like "artboards" and "bounding box" -  as opposed to "pages" and "frames" - do you perhaps mean **Illustrator** and not InDesign?

Comment: This is not a workaround man, you're getting advice here from highly experienced members. This is how InDesign works, you have pages with stuff on them, and then there are objects outside the page, lets call that "on the table". You can have things on the page, on the table, or on both. Hitting the W key as Scott suggested basicly hides away the table and you just see whatever is on your pages. In time you will understand it makes no difference if you leave objects outside the page, because in InDesign all final outputs are generally pulled from page views, not "table" (canvas) views.

Comment: Well, it simply creates more clutter. I constantly work in preview mode already, but when you start to experiment with layouts and move things around, while minding the constrains of the used grid, you clutter up the workspace, thus making it unnecessary hard to focus on the design. When you search for this question, you find out that it is indeed something that is requested for a long time. Illustrator has this already implemented (bc it was requested heavily). Ofc you could say, just turn on preview mode here too, but again, its about a clean workspace. I hope you can understand that

Comment: And if it not possible. Please just say it, instead of saying "just do x". It is not a very nice way of answering a question and also assumes that the one who asked does not know anything about the software he asked about. Why not just saying "is pressing the W key a good alternative for you. I do not know about a solution for your problem. "

Comment: What do you mean "if not possible"? Scott's answer explained to you exactly how it is possible. You wanted to hide things outside your artboard, Scott showed you how to do exactly that. If this does not satisfy your needs, what do you actually need to happen then?

Comment: If you take a look around on this site you'll find many very basic questions which receives very basic answers and are accepted. Scott's answer is simple and polite. Nothing in your question indicates that you know about the "W" shortcut already. You could place your sketches on a separate layer which you could turn off, but you probably know that. What is that function in Illustrator you are mentioning?

Comment: Then let me expand my question: How do I hide all things outside my pages while still maintaining the grid etc. And yes, you are right, the answer is fine. I just got it wrong, but it still does not full-fill my need. I want to have as least clutter as possible while working.

Comment: For me it is still not clear what you are asking. What do you mean by "still maintaining the grid". Could you post a screenshot of what you want (preferrably before/after)?

Comment: If you want less clutter while working, stop creating the clutter.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are looking for a mode which is a mix of *Normal* and *Preview* where everything outside the page is hidden but all grids, guides and extras are still displayed. I don't think that it exists.

I can only suggest these workarounds:

- Keep all your "clutter objects" on a separate layer which you can toggle.
- Draw a shape which covers the entire *Pasteboard* and has a rectangular hole where the page is. Place it in a separate locked layer on top which you can toggle.
- Draw a manual grid. Place it in a separate locked layer on top which you can toggle. This way you can still see the grid in *Preview* mode.
- Enter *Edit > Preferences > Guides & Pasteboard* and make the *Pasteboard* very large. Make sure that all your "clutter objects" are far away from the page. Then you won't see them when you zoom in on a page.
- Keep your "clutter objects" in another document.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the Application Frame I believe.

**Window** > (uncheck) **Application Frame**

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for View -> Overprint Preview. This can really tax your machine if you're designing with hi-res images depending on its performance.